# Using get_word_forms, how do I generate all possible forms of a list of words?

Tags: python, nlp

I am struggling with generating all possible forms of the words in the list below

For instance,

from word_forms.word_forms import get_word_forms

text = ['courses', 'unsurpassable', 'alcohol']
a = [get_word_forms(word) for word in text]
print(a)

[{'n': {'coursings', 'course', 'coursing', 'courses'}, 'a': set(), 'v': {'course', 'coursing', 'courses', 'coursed'}, 'r': {'course'}}, {'n': set(), 'a': {'unsurpassable'}, 'v': set(), 'r': set()}, {'n': {'alcohols', 'alcoholics', 'alcoholic', 'alcohol'},

at the end, I get the result above...
However, I would like to save it into a csv file and I could not find a way to make this happen.

Pls let me know if there is another solution other than the package, 'get_word_forms' to generate all possible forms of a word.

Comment: Please give an _exact and complete_ example of how the CSV should look like for this example. Without that information, your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

English language has its rules, but it's strenuous to get all the inflected forms because there are so many rules and exceptions. I recommend you use APIs from a dictionary website.

(Here's the API from oxford dictionaries: https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation#!/Inflections/get_inflections_source_lang_word_id

Go to the inflections section to get the word forms. You have to sign up to use it, though)